# Bootstrap-3: Alerts without displacing existing content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Image #1: Bootstrap Alert *with* .in class:

[image]

Image #2: Bootstrap Alert *without* .in class (Hides content underneath):

[image]

I've been trying since the past three hours to get alerts working perfectly - without displacing other content. I have read a few blogposts and SO Q&A but not able to achieve the desired effect.

Attempts:

- Closing (Dismissable Alerts) -or- Fading out makes the `display: none;` which effectively displaces content.
- Not fading out but removing the .in class makes the element hidden but still overlapping other elements (See Image #2 and HTML below)
- I've tried using Z-Index to fix this issue but that didn't work.
- I will try to attempt a pop-over alert next, unless I can find a better solution via SO.

HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-message alert-info fade"><p> Joined: StaticRoom </p></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function status(type, msg) {
    var alertHTML = "<div class='alert alert-message alert-" + type + " fade'><p> " + msg + " </p></div>";

    $("#roomInfo").html(alertHTML);
    $(".alert-message").addClass("in");

    setTimeout(function () {
      $(".alert-message").removeClass("in");
    }, 3000);  
}
```

Image #3: Desired:

1. no overlap after alert has expired
2. should not displace existing content when expired:

[image]

Help!

Comment: Wouldn't a modal be better suited for this? You could always put the alert inside a modal.

Comment: @Gavin The info alert is more like a status message. Using a modal for this would provide it too much of user attention, don't you think?

Comment: It sounds like it's changing `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`, have you altered the `in` class?

Comment: @GrahamWalters, Not intentionally. Will use a new copy of bootstrap to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by alert self `height`, `padding` and `margin`. The `.fade` class only change `opacity` value, no more :

**Extract from `bootstrap.css`**

```
.fade{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .15s linear;
    transition:opacity .15s linear
}
.fade.in{
    opacity:1
}
```

What you can do is to override the Bootstrap CSS with :

```
.fade {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition:height .15s linear;
    transition:height .15s linear;
}
.fade.in {
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT **
I didn't get you wanted an absolute positionned alert. So, you don't need any additional classes, just a simple :

```
.movie {
    position: relative;
    width: 430px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 40px; /* give extra space for form */
}
.movie form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
.movie .alert {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px; left: 5px; right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response zessx. One of my iterations had this end result. Unfortunately, this displaces `bar` and `baz` from their absolute position which messes the layout. Is it possible to do this *without* displacing them?

Comment: I updated my fiddle to show you a way to fix your issue, using `position: absolute` on the form, and `padding-bottom` on the parent : **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/uyhDA/3/)**

Comment: Zessx, the new fiddle *still displaces* the input textbox and the button down when the alert appears.

Comment: @ManavKataria Sorry, I misunderstood your needs. Didn't get you want a absolute positioned `.alert`. **[Here is another update.](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/uyhDA/6/)**

Comment: Zessx, This is what I need. Only concern being non-responsiveness. For example, if we make your fiddle's preview window narrow the alert is overlayed by the form | I've accepted your answer nevertheless. Many thanks for your help!